# How to Configuration openapi.json on GCP Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm getting exception while configuring `Openapi.json` on `gcp Endpoints`

> ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot 
>          convert to service config. 
>         'location: "unknown location" 
>          kind: ERROR 
>          message: "Invalid OpenAPI file. Please fix the schema errors:\n\"\": 
>          domain: validation; keyword: additionalProperties; message: additional 
>          properties not permitted; unwanted:

Can you please help in identifying those

Answer (score 1):

It could be the same [issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/134361013).  Google is actively working on it.